# microsoft band How to read heart rate or some sensor data from a custom tile and communicate with mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, microsoft-band

I'm creating a custom tile. I want that tile to read some sensor data such as heart rate and then communicate it with the mobile app. I also want to sync the data MS Health Cloud API

Any help/idea is appreciated

[microsoft-band]

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with the band's sensors in Android, you don't directly interact with a tile. Instead, you can set up listeners to bring the sensor data to your device. From there, you could send the data back to the device through a tile.

For a better idea of how to use the listeners, check out the sample code 
http://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK

Comment: but, some tiles should be activated to get data through listeners.. no..?

Comment: You do not need to add any tiles to get sensor data.